# Creating Compute only OpenStack Cloud

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, openstack, openstack-nova

I've been doing a lot of reading and watching youtube tutorials, but still can't get my hands around openstack. I am only looking for computing no storage or networking. This lead me to search up Nova.  Do you guys have any recommendations or tips on how to get started? I'd like to install openstack nova on my existing Ubuntu VMs.  I won't be hosting external users on this either so no public IPs. I want to have a master machine where I will run my software and then have it go through instances of the openstack computes to do all the computations.

Thank you so much!

Comment: OpenStack is meant to be an IaaS (Infrastructure as a Service), which allows you to create instances, virtual netowrks, volumes, etc. Nova is indeed the service used to create instances. I may be wrong but I don't think it makes any sense to just have nova (you would at least need keystone, glance and probably cinder I believe).

Comment: Oh okay. Do you know where I should go or read on to begin an installation of openstack? I have been reading this but I am still not sure to where to start. http://docs.openstack.org/liberty/install-guide-ubuntu/keystone-install.html

Comment: I also read that devstack and packstack(redhat flavors) might be good for a quick install? Are there an disadvantages with using these over a manual install? I read that devstack doesn't give the environment after a restart. Is this still a problem?

Comment: Sadly I don't know much about devstack but I believe it's  meant for a testing environment (should work with only one physical machine). As for the link you posted, it's for the last version of OpenStack called Liberty, which does not have a full guide yet. I would recommend installing Kilo (the precedent version). You will find a full guide for ubuntu here: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/. You can also find a guide for Red Hat and Suze if you prefer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will check those links out!

Comment: Would it be better to follow a full guide vs packstack for redhat flavors?

Answer (score 0):

There's an Architecture and Design Guide that may be useful for those building compute-focused OpenStack Clouds. Here's a link to the technical considerations: http://docs.openstack.org/arch-design/compute-focus-technical-considerations.html

Comment: Thank you! Would it better to use that link+ manual installation guide instead of using packstack?